# Slice string in Python beginning with first alphabetical character

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have some String like:

'% 0.9 Saline solution'

'2% Taurolidine Lock'

'2 DAA'

...etc

Does have any function can do:

```
>>> a = '% 0.9 Saline solution'
>>> some_clever(a)
>>> 6

>>> a[some_clever(a):]
>>>'Saline solution'
```

Thank you

Comment: There are functions you could write to make it kinda-work (probably using regular expressions. Your samples suggest finding the first word). To make it work well you need **N**atural **L**anguage **P**rocessing which is a very broad subject.

Comment: you can try using regexes for this but you really need to show a proper example of sample input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the index, you can use `next` with a generator expression and `str.isalpha` / `enumerate`. Then use string slicing as normal. Here's a demo:

```
a = '% 0.9 Saline solution'
b = '2% Taurolidine Lock'
c = '2 DAA'

def get_string(x):
    idx = next(i for i, j in enumerate(x) if j.isalpha())
    return x[idx:]

for val in [a, b, c]:
    print(val, ':', get_string(val))

% 0.9 Saline solution : Saline solution
2% Taurolidine Lock : Taurolidine Lock
2 DAA : DAA
```

Comment: Wow, It is of great use for me! I gained a lots from it.